# Passing a float into a constructor that only takes int - cannot modify constructor

Tags: java, oop

I am creating a new class (B) that extends another class (A).

In class A there is a class X getter method, which creates and returns a class X object.

I am NOT allowed to modify class A or X.

The class X constructor currently takes in an int and a string, which have already been inputted in class A. I need to override that method in class B and create a class X object with a float and a string instead of an int and a string, and I can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

```
public class X {

   private int myInt;
   private String myString;

   public X(int myInt, String myString){
      this.myInt = myInt;
      this.myString = myString;
   }
}


public class A {

   protected X getX(){
      return new X(1, "A");
   }
}

public class B extends A {

   @Override
   protected X getX(){
      return new X(1.5, "A"); //Here, I can't input a float. 
   }
}
```

Comment: Well since `X` can't handle a float anyway, you have to convert your `float` into an `int`. Try `Math.ceil`

Comment: If *create a class X object with a float and a string* means also creating an object of a class that **derived from `X`**, then you could create a class `Y` that extends `X` and has a c'tor with float and string. and then in `B`'s `getX()` method you'd init `Y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` can't be downcast to `int` by default.

You can pass the `floor/ceil` value of the `float`

Or, use an implicit conversion `(int)1.5` here